# How to use if statement PyTorch using torch.FloatTensor

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

I am trying to use the **if statement** in my PyTorch code using `torch.FloatTensor` as data type, to speed it up into the **GPU**.

This is my code:

```
import torch
import time
def fitness(x):
     return torch.pow(x, 2)

def velocity(v, gxbest, pxbest, pybest, x, pop):
     return torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)*v + \
            torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)*(pxbest - x) + \
            torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)*(gxbest.expand(x.size(0)) - x)

dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor 
def main():

    pop, xmax, xmin, niter = 300000, 50, -50, 100
    v                      = torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)
    x                      = (xmax-xmin)*torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)+xmin
    y                      = fitness(x)
    [miny, indexminy]      = y.min(0)
    gxbest                 = x[indexminy] 
    pxbest                 = x
    pybest                 = y

    for K in range(niter):

        vnext = velocity(v, gxbest, pxbest, pybest, x, pop)

        xnext = x + vnext
        ynext = fitness(x)
        [minynext, indexminynext]  = ynext.min(0)

        if (minynext < miny):
            miny   = minynext
            gxbest = xnext[indexminynext]

        indexpbest         = (ynext < pybest)
        pxbest[indexpbest] = xnext[indexpbest]
        pybest[indexpbest] = ynext[indexpbest]
        x                  = xnext
        v                  = vnext
main()
```

Unfortanally it is not working. It is giving me a error message and I can not figure it out what is the problem.

> RuntimeError: bool value of non-empty torch.cuda.ByteTensor objects is ambiguous

How can I use the **if** in `PyTorch`? I tried to convert the cuda.Tensor into a numpy array but it did not work also.

```
  minynext = minynext.cpu().numpy()
  miny = miny.cpu().numpy()
```

**PS**: Am I doing the code the efficient/faster way possible ? Or should I change something to achieve faster results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the following simple example:

```
import torch

a = torch.LongTensor([1])
b = torch.LongTensor([5])

print(a > b)
```

Output:

```
 0
[torch.ByteTensor of size 1]
```

Comparing tensors `a` and `b` results in a `torch.ByteTensor` which is obviously not equivalent to `boolean`. So, you can do the following.

```
print(a[0] > b[0]) # False
```

So, you should change your `if` condition as follows.

```
if (minynext[0] < miny[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you compare pyTorch tensors, the output is usually a `ByteTensor`. This data type is not suitable for if statements.

Change the condition inside the `if`:

```
if (minynext[0] < miny[0])
```